# android secure data storage

Tags: android

i am developing one android application. it download videos from server and store it in mobile.

i want to store those video in secure manner.(deny the user from copying. or deny them from viewing the video directly from sdcard)

i found two ways to solve the problem.
      1)Store the video's inside the application.
      2)Encrypt the entire video

but facing some problem in implementing solution
     i)first solution found suitable. but i am fearing that. if we store too much video inside the application .it would become bulkier.and fore the user to uninstall.

ii)but in second solution. i did not find any correct way to do so.

so please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of suggestion :

To store the videos you must have created some folder on SDCARD, so you can hide the folder by putting the "." in front of the name while creating it. on top of this you can encrypt the video file using AES algorithm so it can not be viewed, if copied outside the android it will not be view able. but from your application you can decry-pt the file and view it.

Answer (score 0):

Definitively, you must encrypt the media and that's quite simple. What is more difficult is to play the media, because MediaPlayer only accepts clear contents. A basic way would be to convert an encrypted file to a decrypted one, just for the time of the playing session. A better approach is to build a stream from the file, decrypt that stream and feed it to the player. The hard point is to have a local http server to serve the stream.